# What's so great about this site?

Tags: discussion

Why is French.SE a freaking great place to get help learning a foreign language? There are a million foreign language forums. What makes this one special?

Answer (score 6):

This question is BS, I just had to put it up so I can thank you all just this once.

Because lately I've been begun learning Japanese in my spare time, since I've come far enough with French that I don't have to be constantly pouring effort into it any longer, and I've been using Japanese.SE, and all of a sudden I came to appreciate you all a lot more.

Everyone here gives thorough and complete answers, makes a point to understand what is being asked and answer it precisely, goes out of their way to give extra information, and just generally makes this a fantastically helpful learning environment.

So go ahead and close this. I know. But even so, thanks for doing what you all do.